# Search for specified keywords in files and copy to a new filename based on the keyword

Tags: shell, grep, find, cp

I'm trying to create an .sh script where if any keyword is found in a file then copy that file to the directory `/pathtofolder/keywords/$thefirstkeywordfound`
(overwrite the file if it already exists). Any help would be appreciated with the copy code ( `cp -rf filename /pathtofolder/keywords/$thefirstkeywordfound` ) which is incorrect. It probably also needs a line of code to exclude the path it copies to (/pathtofolder/keywords/)

Note that I want to copy the file into a directory called `/pathtofolder/keywords/$keyword`, creating it if necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are various issues here. First, I have no idea what you're trying to do with `IFS='\n'` so I'll just ignore it. Second, you seem to be copying `filename` not a variable called `filename` and in any case, you are not setting it to anything.

If I understand what you are trying to do correctly, you are looking for something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

## Pass the directory to search in as an argument, 
## easier to use and avoids including /pathfolder/
## as long as your run the script from a different
## directory.
dir="$1";

## Destination directory
dest="$2"

## Don't use capitalized variables in bash,
## environmental vars are CAPS and that could cause
## problems if you use something like $USER. 
keywords=("Florida" "FL" "Miami-Dade" "Aventura" "Bal Harbour" "Bay Harbor Islands")

## Find all files of the right size and pass their names
## to the while loop. Skip any files matching $dest
find "$dir" -size +1c -path "$dest" -prune -o  -type f -print0 | 

## This is to make sure it works with file names containing strange
## characters like newlines. If they don't, you can remove the -print0
## from find and simplify to `while read file name`
while IFS= read -r -d $'\0' filename
do
    for keyword in "${keywords[@]}";
    do
        ## -m 1: stop at first match
        grep -qm 1 -Fw "$keyword" "$filename" && 

        ## Create a dir for the keyword if it does not exist
        mkdir -p "$dest"/"$keyword" &&

        ## copy the file if grep found a match (that's what && above means)
        cp -vf "$filename" "$dest"/"$keyword"/ &&

        ## move to the next filename if the copy succeds
        break 
    done
done
```

Save the script somewhere, `foo.sh` and run it giving it the folder to be searched as an argument:

```
./foo.sh "/source/dir" "/target/dir"
```

Comment: I made an edit above explaining my current issues with your code. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @Guest please don't edit _my_ answer to ask for more information. Edit _your_ post instead. You might want to have a look at our [help] or take the [tour] to understand how the stack exchange sites work. Anyway, sorry and please see updated answer, I had a silly syntax error.

Comment: root@death:~# ./sort-miami.sh "/root/unsorted" "/root/sorted"
grep: : No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory
grep: : No such file or directory

Comment: @Guest argh! I seem to have left the error in there again, sorry. Try again, make sure the while ends in `filename` and not in `file name` as I had it. It is correct now.

Comment: It works perfect. Just one more question sir. Will it copy the same file to multiple /paths/ example /sorted/fl /sorted/miami /sorted/florida or only one time for the first key word discovered... then the script will move onto the next file.

Comment: @Guest no, it will overwrite the same path. So that `/sorted/miami` will always be the _last_ file found that contained the string `miami`. Isn't that what you wanted?

Comment: Thanks for the help you have no idea how much I appreciate it. Have a great night!

Comment: @Guest you're very welcome, thanks for the accept!

Comment: Ugh oh I found an issue.. I wasn't paying close enough attention. `/root/unsorted/example.html' -> `/root/sorted/Florida'
`/root/unsorted/example2.html' -> `/root/sorted/howard'

it should be saving them to:

`/root/unsorted/example.html' -> `/root/sorted/Florida/example.html'
`/root/unsorted/example2.html' -> `/root/sorted/howard/example2.html'

Comment: @Guest OK, but that is not what you asked for. The new script creates a directory as requested.

Comment: Thanks for saving the day again. I apologize for being unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with a somewhat complex `awk` command:

```
timp@helez:~/tmp/cp_find_test$ ls
command.sh  command.sh~  test.1  test.2  test.3
timp@helez:~/tmp/cp_find_test$ cat test.1 
Aventura
Whatever
Florida
timp@helez:~/tmp/cp_find_test$ cat test.2
Random stuff
Floridaasdklfj
timp@helez:~/tmp/cp_find_test$ cat test.3
FL
timp@helez:~/tmp/cp_find_test$ ./command.sh
cp -rf ./test.3 /pathtofolder/keywords/FL
cp -rf ./command.sh /pathtofolder/keywords/Florida
cp -rf ./test.1 /pathtofolder/keywords/Aventura
cp -rf ./command.sh~ /pathtofolder/keywords/Florida
timp@helez:~/tmp/cp_find_test$ cat command.sh
KEYWORDS=("Florida" "FL" "Miami-Dade" "Aventura" "Bal Harbour" "Bay Harbor Islands")
IFS=$'\n'
find . -size +1c -type f ! -exec grep -oHwF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"; last_line=""} {if (last_line!=$1) {print "cp -rf", $1, "/pathtofolder/keywords/"$2}; last_line=$1}'
```

I added a `-o` to your `grep` so that it would only print the matching parts of the line, and then used `awk` to build the `cp` commands.

The reason I didn't use `-m 1` in `grep` instead of the `if (last_line!=$1) {...}; last_line=$1` was because if there's multiple matches on the same line it would print them all out as separate lines:

```
timp@helez:~/tmp/cp_find_test$ ./command.sh
cp -rf ./test.3 /pathtofolder/keywords/FL
cp -rf ./command.sh /pathtofolder/keywords/Florida
cp -rf ./command.sh /pathtofolder/keywords/FL
cp -rf ./command.sh /pathtofolder/keywords/Miami-Dade
cp -rf ./command.sh /pathtofolder/keywords/Aventura
cp -rf ./command.sh /pathtofolder/keywords/Bal Harbour
cp -rf ./command.sh /pathtofolder/keywords/Bay Harbor Islands
cp -rf ./test.1 /pathtofolder/keywords/Aventura
cp -rf ./command.sh~ /pathtofolder/keywords/Florida
cp -rf ./command.sh~ /pathtofolder/keywords/FL
cp -rf ./command.sh~ /pathtofolder/keywords/Miami-Dade
cp -rf ./command.sh~ /pathtofolder/keywords/Aventura
cp -rf ./command.sh~ /pathtofolder/keywords/Bal Harbour
cp -rf ./command.sh~ /pathtofolder/keywords/Bay Harbor Islands
timp@helez:~/tmp/cp_find_test$ cat command.sh
KEYWORDS=("Florida" "FL" "Miami-Dade" "Aventura" "Bal Harbour" "Bay Harbor Islands")
IFS=$'\n'
#find . -size +1c -type f ! -exec grep -oHwF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"; last_line=""} {if (last_line!=$1) {print "cp -rf", $1, "/pathtofolder/keywords/"$2}; last_line=$1}'
find . -size +1c -type f ! -exec grep -m 1 -oHwF "${KEYWORDS[*]}" {} \; | awk 'BEGIN {FS=":"} {print "cp -rf", $1, "/pathtofolder/keywords/"$2}'
```

Answer (score 0):

I Think you need more than a simple pipeline to do that. So, I propose something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
KEYWORD_PATTERN='Florida|FL|Miami-Dade|Aventura|Bal Harbour|Bay Harbor Islands'
find . -type f |
while read FNAME
do
    if grep -Ew -q "$KEYWORD_PATTERN" $FNAME
    then
        KEYWORD=$(grep -Ew -o "$KEYWORD_PATTERN" $FNAME  | head -1)
        echo mv $FNAME /pathtofolder/keywords/$KEYWORD
    fi

done
```

This takes advantage of extended (`-E`) GNU `grep` flags, `-w` and `-o`.  Without those two flags, you'd have to put something like a little Perl program that can break "words" out of lines of text, select a word that matches of the keywords and uses that as the file name.